# Remover caractere em Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

tudo bem?

Estou fazendo um script de leitura de um log no meu servidor para pegar apenas algumas partes que me interessam e jogar em um .csv.

O script é bem simples, segue:

```
  #!/bin/bash


export TMPARQ=/datasets/SCRIPTS/TMP/logjob.txt
export FILTER=/datasets/SCRIPTS/TMP/logjob2.txt
PROJ=$1
JOB=$2

cd /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/
. ./dsenv
dsjob -logsum $PROJ $JOB > $TMPARQ

grep -A 1 "rows inserted on the current node" $TMPARQ > $FILTER

cat $FILTER | grep INFO | cut -d':' -f1-3 | cut -c16-42 > /datasets/SCRIPTS/TMP/data.txt

grep "inserted on the current node:" $TMPARQ | cut -d":" -f3 > /datasets/SCRIPTS/TMP/volumetria.txt

cd /datasets/SCRIPTS/TMP/
paste data.txt volumetria.txt > GeraInfoVolumetria.txt

cat GeraInfoVolumetria.txt
cat GeraInfoVolumetria.txt >> HistoricoVolumetria.csv
```

Estou com uma dúvida ao gerar o arquivo volumetria.txt
Uma linha completa do log original é a seguinte:

> OrclLog,1: Number of rows inserted on the current node: 66.

Preciso pegar o valor depois dos ":", no caso 66
O que acontece é que o arquivo volumetria.txt está segundo gravado também com o ponto após o número. Tentei usar um grep -v "." porém remove toda a linha.

Aqui está o exemplo do txt:

```
Jan 10 19:37:28 2019     0.
Jan 10 20:08:33 2019     66.
Jan 10 20:08:33 2019     66.
```

Os números podem variar em diferentes caracteres, até mais que 9999
Alguém consegue me ajudar a tirar esse bendito ponto? haha

Obrigado

Comment: Sou novo em shell script. Se poder deixar comentários e sugestões sobre o código, ficarei extremamente agradecido o/

Comment: Utilizando um PCRE é possível capturar o número desejado na expressão com um único grep.

Answer (score 3):

Há diversas maneiras de fazer isto e uma delas, usando o `cut`, seria:

```
echo "OrclLog,1: Number of rows inserted on the current node: 66." |\
    cut -d":" -f3 | cut -d"." -f1
```

E o resultado seria " 66" (ainda há o espaço na frente).